# Ruby on Rails - Link_to with icon instead of a slash

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, icons, link-to, slash

i want to show an small icon instead of a textlink.
using this piece of code:

```
      <li>
      <%= link_to '', :class => 'nav-icon' do %>
          <span class="icon-home">Home</span><%= root_path %>
      <% end %>
      </li>
```

but rails now shows me the icon followed by a /
is there any way to avoid that behavior?

Comment: try <%= link_to root_path, :class => 'nav-icon' do %><span class="icon-home">Home</span><% end %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li>
  <%= link_to root_path, :class => 'nav-icon' do %>
    <span class="icon-home">Home</span>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

The `/` displayed after your icon is generated by `<%= root_path %>`.

`<%= %>` seems:

> please ruby, write this on my html.

so ruby wrote your `root_path` variable, and your `root_path` is equal to `/`.

remove your `<%= root_path %>` after `<span class="icon-home">Home</span>` and everything will be ok.

Comment: You guys are awesome! Thanks for the super fast help!
It works perfectly now!

Comment: No problems, dont hesitate to come here back if you still have problems!

Answer (score 2):

Following should work

```
  <li>
  <%= link_to '', :class => 'nav-icon' do %>
      <span class="icon-home">Home</span>
  <% end %>
  </li>
```

Reason: the `/` is coming due to this code `<%= root_path %>`

and writing just `<%= link_to '', :class => 'nav-icon' do %>` will create **link with empty href**

I think you should give your path in the first argument of `link_to` as follows

```
link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # your icon code
end
```